# Force output of ascii string as bytes

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

If I am trying to explore non-ascii string in interactive python session:

```
>>> 'юникод'
'\xd1\x8e\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb4'
```

it gets me string as bytes (since `str` in python 2 is actually bytes)

I want to get same representation for ascii string, but python implicitly converts it to string representation

```
>>> 'unicode'
'unicode'
```

How could I disable such behavior?
Or I should build such functionality manually?

Comment: Do you mean you want each character in hex. notation?

Comment: @cdarke yep same as non-ascii string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
s = 'unicode'
print ''.join(['\\x%02x' % (ord(c)) for c in s])
```

Gives:

```
\x75\x6e\x69\x63\x6f\x64\x65
```

Comment: Mildly clever alternative to avoid a lot of `ord` calls is to convert all at once to `bytearray` (which is equivalent to Py3 `bytearray`, including iterating to get `int` values), then `map` with a built-in function so you could do `''.join(map('\\x{:02x}'.format, bytearray(s)))` which moves all looping to the C layer (in the CPython reference interpreter). Note: Your answer is fine (upvoted), I just enjoy finding ways to let Python do more of the work below the Python layer.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to quickly inspect the hex values:

```
>>> s = 'unicode'
>>> s.encode('hex_codec')
'756e69636f6465'
```